# Fire base Update c++ / how to detect string in URL

Tags: c++, qt, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change some Data in my realtime firebase based on the id.
I want to customize my Https but it does not work.
when i add + id to my URL i got a failure: QNetworkRequest newAdminRequest(QUrl("gymmanagment-a6c01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.a…" + id)) –

```
void DatabaseHandler::AddAdmin(QString name, QString password, 
QString email, QString Geburtsdatum){
m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager( this);

QVariantMap newAdmin;

newAdmin["Name"] = name;
newAdmin["Password"] = password;
newAdmin["Email"] = email;
QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant( newAdmin );
std::string id = "-N7pPxSHoPVlyEi8e0xW";
QNetworkRequest newAdminRequest(QUrl("https://gymmanagment-a6c01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Admin.json"+ id));

newAdminRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QString("application/json"));
m_networkManager->put(newAdminRequest, jsonDoc.toJson() );}
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: when i add + id to my URL i got a failure: QNetworkRequest newAdminRequest(QUrl("https://gymmanagment-a6c01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Admin.json"+ id))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the '**id**' as if it were an '**endpoint**', like this:

```
https://gymmanagment-a6c01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Admin/-N7pPxSHoPVlyEi8e0xW.json
```

For general case, you can join each part:

```
QString id = "-N7pPxSHoPVlyEi8e0xW";
QString base = "https://gymmanagment-a6c01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Admin/";
QUrl url = base + id + ".json";
yourRequest->setUrl(url);
```

Then, **put** your changes.

Comment: I know it works like that  but i have to make in general case